# Probability of dying exactly during a specific year

Tags: probability

Suppose we know, for each year $k$, that your chance of dying from all causes is $d_k$: during your first year of life your chance of dying before you turn 2 is $d_1$; during the second year, your chance not to make it to year 3 is $d_2$, etc. We want to know the probability $D_n$ that you will die exactly during year $n$. My guess would be this:

$$D_n = (1 - d_1)(1 - d_2)\dots(1 - d_{n-1})d_n$$

Does this make sense? Intuitively I would say so, but I'm not convinced. My confusion stems from the fact I am not sure whether we're talking about $n$ different, dependent events each with its own probability, or one single event with different probabilities of happening at different times. Thanks!

Comment: "...assuming that you didn't die until now..." On what do you base this interpretation? $P(E_k)$ is said to be the probability of the event that you die in year $k$. So unconditional.

Comment: It seems that you are making confusion between the events "you die exactly on year $k$" and "you die on some year $\le k$".

Comment: @drhab $P(E_k)$ should be the probability of death that a person has in general when they hit age $k$. If you don't make it to age $k$, though, $P(E_k)$ does not make sense for you. That's my interpretation.

Comment: @Crostul Can you elaborate? I'm not even trying to compute anything about the event "you die on some year $\leq k$", so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Fine, but then it is simply wrong and confusing to name it as "the event that your death occurs in year $k$". You should repair that.

Comment: Actually, *your* $P(E_k)$ is not the probability of an event but at most of events $E_k$ in distinct probability spaces. If $F_k$ denotes the event that you die on the age of $k$ and $H_k=F_0\cup\cdots\cup F_k$ then *your* $P(E_k)$ equals $P(F_k\mid H_{k-1}^{\complement})$ which is a conditional probability. If you insist on looking at $E_k$ as an event then for every $k$ you need another underlying probability space.

Comment: @drhab I tried to simplify and clarify my question—I had probably exposed it in an unnecessarily complicated fashion and screwed it all up in the process, sorry. Does it make more sense this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does make sense.

Let $F_n$ denote the event that you die in your $n$-th year.

Let $E_{n}$ denote the event that you live longer than $n$ years.

Then $P(F_n\mid E_{n-1})=d_n$ and $P(F_n^{\complement}\mid E_{n-1})=1-d_n$.

And $E_n=F_1^{\complement}\cap\cdots\cap F_n^{\complement}$ so that: $$P(E_n)=P(F_n^{\complement}\mid E_{n-1})P(E_{n-1})=(1-d_n)P(E_{n-1})$$leading to: $$P(E_n)=(1-d_1)(1-d_2)\cdots(1-d_n)$$so that:

$$P(F_n)=P(F_n\cap E_{n-1})=P(E_{n-1})P(F_n\mid E_{n-1})=(1-d_1)(1-d_2)\cdots(1-d_{n-1})d_n$$